# In OpenCL, what is the difference between platform, context, and device?

Tags: opencl, gpgpu, gpu

I am new to OpenCL programming. What is the difference between device, context, and platform?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A platform is a specific OpenCL implementation, for instance AMD APP, NVIDIA or Intel OpenCL. A context is a platform with a set of available devices for that platform. And the devices are the actual processors (CPU, GPU etc.) that perform calculations.

So if you use the Intel platform, a valid context with this platform would include a CPU device. While if you use the NVIDIA platform, a valid context would include an NVIDIA GPU device.

Comment: Could you expand your answer with an example of different contexts on a single platform?

Comment: Sure. Lets say you have a system with 1 CPU and 1 GPU both from AMD. Both will be available with the AMD OpenCL platform. One context could be with only the CPU, another context could have only the GPU, while a third context could contain both the CPU and the GPU. Having multiple devices in a context gives more data sharing options and synchronization.